# My creature electricity production mechanism

Tags: biology, creature-design, science-fiction, xenobiology

In my organism electricity is usually generated by absorbing free electrons in the air and using them in combination with a proton-laced electrical sack to create an electric current ,which is then released from a portion of the animal body as a discharge of raw energy.
what material is my organism skin made of that allows it to absorb free electron in air and how would the structure of proton laced electrical sack work ? what is this made of ?

Comment: what are they doing with the electricity, using free electrons your not going to get much more than a tiny zap.

Comment: My questions how to collect them and all other mentioned in question

Comment: Oh look, a mysterious and unnecessary `[hard science]` tag. Creating new accounts to try and wriggle out of problems with old ones is maybe a little frowned upon, but doing the _exact same thing_ with the new account as you did with the old just seems silly.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, for another time, if you smell something fishy you can flag for moderator attention

Comment: @L.Dutch I wasn't certain that creating a new account was a bad thing, but I'll make a note for next time.

Comment: @StarfishPrime good. Creating a new account to circumvent system or moderator imposed sanctions is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

**Fur.**

[image: static cat]

https://imgur.com/r/aww/gmx1gBG

As opposed to this cat which is relatively insulated with no path to ground, your creature can extend a conductive spike into the earth and so allow collected electrons a path down to ground.  The electrons must traverse the sac on the way, doing work en route.  They don't want to do work but they want badly to get to ground and through the sac is the only option.

Comment: Shielding of the excess charge those electrons builds up is gonna be a problem. After a short while, no free electrons will be willing to get close to the collecting fur. A second problem: the cat needs to start positively charged to attract those free electrons - which means it will need to repel first some electrons "bound" in its body. But, if it already have the capacity to separate charges, why the heck does it still need to capture free electrons in the first place? Also, note the `hard-science` tag on the question.